# youtube video in galleria not working on ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, youtube, galleria

In galleria plugin since youtube switched to V3 youtube video are not working any more on iPad, and get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 (Gone)
i found [this post](http://support.galleria.io/discussions/problems/17294-youtube-api-v2-deprecated) i fixed the error but video would not play

i changed this part of the script comparing the one attached in post with mine

```
getUrl: function() {
            //return PROT + '//gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + this.id + '?v=3&alt=json-in-script&callback=?';
            return '//www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' + this.id + '&part=contentDetails&key=[my API code]';
        },
```

somebody suggest to add &callback=? at the end but i just get an error

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalidParameter","message":"Invalid value for parameter callback: ?","locationType":"parameter","location":"callback"}],"code":400,"message":"Invalid value for parameter callback: ?"}}
```

without &callback=? at the end of the url i can see the video after clicking on image cover, but it is paused with the red youtube play button in the center, if i try to touch play button video does not play

I'm not sure that JS error and video not playing is related, i don't understand what getUrl does